# How use a self-signed certificate in ReactNative when I use fetch to request data?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

The oc code is here:

```
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef)certData);

[postDataRequest setClientCertificates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)cert]];
```